# Can anyone tell me how to view data on two tables in the form of charts in Apache Superset

Tags: postgresql, apache-superset

I am working on apache superset,but I am not knowing how to retrieve data from two tables on a chart

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1:** Join your two tables at the DB level and save it as a view or a materialised view. Then add the view as a dataset to superset.

**Option 2:** Go to SQL lab in Superset and join your tables and save as a virtual dataset. This is similar to a view on the DB.